Android studio emulator disappeared and i cant find it
I was working with Android Studio and had my emulator running on a second screen. However, when I opened Android Studio today and tried to run my code, everything worked smoothly, except I couldn't find the emulator window anywhere.
I tried going to File > Project Structure and adding the Android module, but that didn’t solve the issue. Any suggestions on how to recover my emulator window?

What host system are you using?  Have you checked the window list (Alt-Tab on WIndows)?

Cheack if it is minimised, or shouldn't you click run button to activate emulator window?.

your emulator isn't disappeared, its just that the new tabs had been there in right side toolbar of the android studio, so all you need to do is to find the emulator  tab inside your right side toolbar,
The right toolbar would be looking like this.. mine is different as i have removed unnecessary tools from there.

This is my toolbar, you might have other tools inside your toolbar, remove what you aren't using by right-click on it and remove from sidebar option like this,

so when you remove unnecessary tools the emulator tab would be visible you can drag and drop tools as per your priority of the usage.
